# $I\otimes I$ is torsion-free for a principal ideal $I$ in domain $R$ 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Question: Suppose $I$ is a principal ideal in a domain $R$. Prove that the $R$ module  $I\otimes_R I$ is torsion-free.

I know this question has already been answered here:

[$I\otimes I$ is torsion-free for a principal ideal $I$ in domain $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1371734/660)

I truly appreciate the beauty and simplicity of the given answer. However, I am interested in what the original author has asked about, namely:

**If you can show that every simple tensor is torsion-free, can you conclude that every element in  $I\otimes_R I$ is torsion-free?**

Such a claim has been made for example here:

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~clayton/courses/503/503_midterm.pdf

I would appreciate your help,

Comment: Every tensor in $I \otimes_R I$ (since $I \cong R$ as $R$-modules) is simple. So yes to the specific question you are asking. Maybe you are asking a more general question, if so, you should phrase it so...

Comment: @AreaMain: I believe the OP is asking whether the proof in the link quoted is correct. That proof contains a claim that if the simple tensors in $I \otimes I$ are torsion free, then so is $I \otimes I$ without any justification (suggesting that it is true for non-principal $I$). I agree that the phrasing of the  question could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is principal then every element of $I$ is of the form $a\mu$ for some fixed $a\in R$ and some $\mu\in R$. It follows that $I\otimes I$ is generated, as an $R$-module, by the tensor $a\otimes a$.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is an integral domain and $I$ is any ideal of $R$ (not necessarily principal) then no simple tensor in $I \otimes_R I$ can be a torsion element: if $r(x\otimes y) = 0$, then $rxy = 0$ by consideration of the linear mapping $I \otimes_R I \to I$ induced by the bilinear mapping $(x, y) \mapsto xy$. But there are many integral domains with ideals $I$ such that $I \otimes_R I$ is not torsion-free: in the integral domain $k[x, y]$ (where $k$ is any field) the ideal $(x, y)$ has this behavior (see [How does one show that this tensor product is not torsion-free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255304/how-does-one-show-that-this-tensor-product-is-not-torsion-free/255344)). So the proof in the link you quoted is not correct (all it proves is what I wrote in the first sentence of this answer).